# pd.DataFrame: get average value per id between two datetimes; if NaN, get last non-NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Say I have the following `pd.DataFrame` ([df.to_dict()](https://justpaste.it/8azje)):

```
    eff_timestamp       val         id  begin_timestamp     end_timestamp
0   2021-01-01 00:00:00 0.677085    1   2021-01-01 02:00:00 2021-01-01 05:30:00
1   2021-01-01 01:00:00 -0.356381   1   2021-01-01 02:00:00 2021-01-01 05:30:00
2   2021-01-01 02:00:00 1.697311    1   2021-01-01 02:00:00 2021-01-01 05:30:00
3   2021-01-01 03:00:00 0.910820    1   2021-01-01 02:00:00 2021-01-01 05:30:00
4   2021-01-01 04:00:00 -1.024458   1   2021-01-01 02:00:00 2021-01-01 05:30:00
5   2021-01-01 05:00:00 -0.430950   1   2021-01-01 02:00:00 2021-01-01 05:30:00
6   2021-01-01 06:00:00 -1.124934   1   2021-01-01 02:00:00 2021-01-01 05:30:00
7   2021-01-01 07:00:00 0.791751    1   2021-01-01 02:00:00 2021-01-01 05:30:00
8   2021-01-02 00:00:00 0.629035    2   2021-01-02 02:00:00 2021-01-02 05:30:00
9   2021-01-02 01:00:00 0.445033    2   2021-01-02 02:00:00 2021-01-02 05:30:00
10  2021-01-02 02:00:00 NaN         2   2021-01-02 02:00:00 2021-01-02 05:30:00
11  2021-01-02 03:00:00 NaN         2   2021-01-02 02:00:00 2021-01-02 05:30:00
12  2021-01-02 04:00:00 NaN         2   2021-01-02 02:00:00 2021-01-02 05:30:00
13  2021-01-02 05:00:00 NaN         2   2021-01-02 02:00:00 2021-01-02 05:30:00
14  2021-01-02 06:00:00 NaN         2   2021-01-02 02:00:00 2021-01-02 05:30:00
15  2021-01-02 07:00:00 -0.637133   2   2021-01-02 02:00:00 2021-01-02 05:30:00
```

I would like to get one value per unique id, that holds the mean of `val` for the period between `begin_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` (based on `eff_timestamp`). If that value returns `np.nan`, I would like to get the last available value that is not `np.nan`. I know how to get the mean of 'val' between the begin and end timestamp:

```
sliced = df[(df.eff_timestamp > df.begin_timestamp) & (df.eff_timestamp < df.end_timestamp)]
sliced
>>>
    eff_timestamp       val         id  begin_timestamp     end_timestamp
3   2021-01-01 03:00:00 0.910820    1   2021-01-01 02:00:00 2021-01-01 05:30:00
4   2021-01-01 04:00:00 -1.024458   1   2021-01-01 02:00:00 2021-01-01 05:30:00
5   2021-01-01 05:00:00 -0.430950   1   2021-01-01 02:00:00 2021-01-01 05:30:00
11  2021-01-02 03:00:00 NaN         2   2021-01-02 02:00:00 2021-01-02 05:30:00
12  2021-01-02 04:00:00 NaN         2   2021-01-02 02:00:00 2021-01-02 05:30:00
13  2021-01-02 05:00:00 NaN         2   2021-01-02 02:00:00 2021-01-02 05:30:00

sliced.groupby('id').val.mean()
>>>
id
1   -0.181529
2         NaN
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Because id=2 only has NaN values between `2021-01-02 02:00:00` and `2021-01-02 05:30:00`, this returns NaN. However, in that case, I'd like to get the value 0.445033 because that's the last non-NaN value for that patient. How would I do this? The output should thus be:

```
id
1   -0.181529
2   0.445033
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: `If that value returns np.nan, I would like to get the last available value that is not np.nan.`. How is this last available value is defined? For example: when `id` = 2, why should it be 0.445033, instead of -0.637133?

Comment: @akilat90 it should be the last non-nan value before the period between `begin_timestamp` and `end_timestamp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
idx=df[df['val'].isna()].index-1

out=sliced.groupby('id')['val'].mean().fillna(df.loc[idx].groupby('id',sort=False)['val'].first())
```

Output of `out`:

```
id
1   -0.181529
2    0.445033
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from your code, once you've determined that for a given id (let's
call it `nid`) you have a NaN value, we can determine the index where the slice begins:

```
slice_start = sliced[sliced['id'] == nid].index[0]
```

Now we can get the portion of the 'val' series that comes before the slice:

```
portion = df.loc[:slice_start, 'val'][df['id'] == nid]
```

and use `last_valid_index()` to get the value you want:

```
val = df.loc[portion.last_valid_index(), 'val']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the dataframe that you're leaving out when you've obtained the `sliced` above. Call it `left_out`:

```
# just the negation of what you've used
left_out = df[~((df.eff_timestamp > df.begin_timestamp) & (df.eff_timestamp < df.end_timestamp))]
```

Then, as per the comment above, in order to filter out values before the `begin_timestamp`:

```
values_before_the_period = left_out.sort_values(["eff_timestamp", "begin_timestamp"])[left_out['eff_timestamp'] < left_out['begin_timestamp']]
```

Note that `sort_values` may not be necessary, if it's already done.

With this, we can obtain a mapping that contains the last non-nan value before the period between begin_timestamp and end_timestamp.

```
mapping = values_before_the_period.groupby('id').tail(1)[['id', 'val']].set_index('id').to_dict()

# {'val': {1: -0.3563813741494545, 2: 0.445032587866597}}
```

Make a series out of that:

```
mapping_s = pd.Series((mapping['val']))
mapping_s

1   -0.356381
2    0.445033
dtype: float64
```

Now, this can be combined with `s` which you've obtained, in a way that only the `np.nan` values will be replaced in `s`.

```
s.combine_first(mapping_s)

1   -0.181529
2    0.445033
Name: val, dtype: float64
```